# jQuery & RegEX to parse image name

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to write a jQuery snippet of code, that will parse an image name containing width, height, and extensions and assign those values to variables.

Image Name Format: `DSCN0551-130x130.jpg` (name-widthxheight.extension)

I want to try and pull our the width, the height, and the extension and assign them to variables.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'DSCN0551-130x130.jpg';
var matches = str.match(/(.+)-(\d+)x(\d+)\.(\w+)$/);
var name = matches[1];
var width = matches[2];
var height = matches[3];
var extension = matches[4];
```

By adding the anchor to the end, you can basically read the regex from right to left. And then after the leftmost `-` that is relevant to your structure, `.+` matches anything that's left (no matter what characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
var g='DSCN0551-130x130.jpg'.match(/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.([a-z]+)/i)
//g[1] = width
//g[2] = height
//g[3] = ext
```

or better : 
*If you only want the first match found, you might want to use regexp.exec(string) instead.*

```
var g=/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.([a-z]+)/i.exec('DSCN0551-130x130.jpg')
//g[1] = width
//g[2] = height
//g[3] = ext
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/dL89D/1/

```
var imgName = "DSCN0551-130x130.jpg";
var args = imgName.match(/(.*)-(.*)x(.*)\.(.*)/).slice(1);

alert("name: " + args[0] + //name: DSCN0551
      " width: " + args[1] + //width: 130
      " height: " + args[2] + //height: 130
      " extension: " + args[3]);​ //extension: jpg
```

Comment: If the file name contains a dash and an x, this might break.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = "DSCN0-551-130x130.jpg";

var props = img.split(/-(\d+)x(\d+)\./);

var name = props[0];
var width = props[1];
var height = props[2];
var extension = props[3];
```