# How to pull a number out of a string in JavaScript and a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript -- I need to pull out and examine the number that appears just before the "jpg" file extension, in this case "300".

var filename = 2012_honda_odyssey_passenger-minivan_ex_s_oem_2_300.jpg

What's the best way to pull this number out -- I can alway assume it will be between the last "_" in the string and this final "." before the file extension.

I'm guessing that I need to do something with regex. Like this ....

```
var num = parseInt(filename.match(/some-regex-here/), 10);
```

**addition**

I did come up with this ... but it seemed very kludgy.

```
var filename = "2012_honda_odyssey_passenger-minivan_ex_s_oem_2_300.jpg";
var num = parseInt(filename.split('_').splice(-1,1).toString().split(".").splice(0,1).toString(), 10);
```

Comment: See me answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626898/jquery-regex-to-parse-image-name/12627019#12627019). It's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel a regex is overkill for something this simple, I would just use this:

```
var start = filename.lastIndexOf('_') + 1; 
var end = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
var num = parseInt(filename.substring(start, end), 10);
```

Comment: I feel eventhough this is an acceptable answer to the situation where the OP is. It doesn't answer the real question "how to pull a number out of regex ? ". Can you please edit the answer to help people who came here actually looking for a way to parse the number from a string. @ggreiner 's answer seems closer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filename = "2012_honda_odyssey_passenger-minivan_ex_s_oem_2_300.jpg";
var regex = /^.*_(\d+)\.jpg?$/;
var match = regex.exec(filename);
var number = Number(match[1]);

console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression such as this: `_(\d+)\..+?$` should allow you to match and extract the number to a group. The regex above should match an underscore (`_`) followed by one ore more digits (`\d+`), followed by a period (`\.`) which in turn is followed by some letters (`.+?`) and finally the end of the string (`$`).

You can then refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) previous SO question to see how you can later access these groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num=parseInt(filename.replace(/^.*?([0-9]+).jpg$/i,"$1"),10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding regexes is usually best, unless you're doing complex string pattern matching is usually. Something like will get what you want:

```
var num = +filename.substring(
  filename.lastIndexOf('_') + 1,
  filename.lastIndexOf('.')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
'2012_honda_odyssey_passenger-minivan_ex_s_oem_2_300.jpg'.match(/[0-9]+(?=\.jpg)/)[0]
```